# JavaScript slack api jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slack-api

My question is very simple and I thought creating this program would only take a couple hours. However now I have been working on it all day trying to figure out what I could be doing wrong.

All I am trying to do is post messages to slack using their [postMessage api](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). I have been able to send messages succesfully using slacks [testing methods](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test).

This is the url that is outputted by the test

```
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xoxp-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx&channel=XXXXXXXX&text=Just%20need%20the%20url&as_user=jheuman&pretty=1
```

I then decided to try it out locally using this html file served from my file system

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Slack API</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="test()">Test</button>
    <button onClick="test2()">Authorization Test</button>

<script>
    function test() {
        var apiUrl = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage";
        var token = "xoxp-xxxxx...";//my token has been omitted for security;
        var channel = "#general";
        var text = "Testing slack api";
        var user = "jheuman";
        var actualToken = "Bearer " + token;


        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Authorization':actualToken,
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },

            data: JSON.stringify({
                "channel": channel,
                "text": text,
                "as_user": user
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        });


    };

    function test2() {
        var apiUrl = "https://slack.com/api/auth.test";
        var token = "xoxp-xxxxx..."; //my token has been omitted for security
        var channel = "#general";
        var text = "Testing slack api";
        var user = "jheuman";
        var actualToken = "Bearer" + token;


    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Authorization':actualToken
        },
        type: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl,
    })
        .done(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});


    };
</script>
```

But when I click either button I get the following error:

```
Failed to load https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage: Request header field 
Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight 
response.
```

So per a friends Suggestion I tried it out on a server. I used [Web Server For Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/related?hl=en) to serve it up on port 8887. First without setting cors headers and then with setting cors headers. Both to no avail. I received the same error.

As you can see I also tried the auth.test call but I receive the same error.

Slack specifically states that they prefer an authorization header and that the api can handle json data.

**Other things I have tried:**

Having no header field with token in data:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    'token':actualToken,
    'channel': channel,
    'text': text,
    'as_user': user
}),
dataType: 'json',
processData: false,
type: 'POST',
url: apiUrl
```

Errors received:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_form_data"}
```

Having no header field with token in data  without 'Bearer':

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    'token':token,
    'channel': channel,
    'text': text,
    'as_user': user
}),
dataType: 'json',
processData: false,
type: 'POST',
url: apiUrl
```

Errors received:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_form_data"}
```

**Things I have looked into but don't think will effect outcome**

[The type of token](https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types)

So how do I get this post request to work?

I am not set on jquery or ajax, it is just what I have used in the past so if you have a different request library to use I'm all ears.

If you need more information I will try to give it to you

Comment: Aha, So you think if I use nodejs the call will go through just fine? That was my end goal, just wanted to test it out before I tried putting it on a server

Comment: Did you try removing the hash from the channel name?

Comment: @vol7ron I use the 7 digit thing at the end of the URL but did not want to post that in here, so that is not the problem but thank you.

Comment: Based on your error message, I assumed that to be a long shot anyhow ;) I still need to read your question more thoroughly, but I’m curious if you couldn’t create a public Slack channel with token for others to test more thoroughly. CORS is an unwieldy beast and it seems like some answers here ought to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since configuring CORS correctly for sending data with content-type `application/json` can be tricky, I would suggest to send the request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is the default for AJAX.

Example:

```
var apiUrl = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage";
var token = MY_TOKEN;
var channel = "general";
var text = "Testing slack api";
var user = "jheuman";

 $.ajax({                   
    data: {
        "token": token,
        "channel": channel,
        "text": text,
        "as_user": user
    },                      
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'POST',           
    url: apiUrl,
    error: function(xhr,status,error){              
        console.log("error: " + error);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("result: " + data);
    }
});
```

In case you get CORS errors, you can add `crossDomain: true`

This solution is tested and works when run in a normal browser.

Comment: Happy to help. Btw. I would not recommend to run this code in the browser other then for testing, since it would expose your token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reply to that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS headers to make this work. One of which is indeed Access-Control-Allow-Headers. That header needs to contain the same values the Access-Control-Request-Headers header contained (or more).

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol explains this setup in more detail.

```
headers: {
                'Authorization':actualToken,
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'x-requested-with'
            },
```

Comment: Your server needs header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: The API called is running on a vendor server, which he has no control over

Comment: I suspect Brian is right. Setting cors is done server side which is why I was having such trouble finding a solution to my problem since I cant change the slack server. I tried this and it does not work. But thank you for trying to help!